# How to set correct permissions for .pem file under Ubuntu on WSL?

Tags: chmod, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` under `WSL` and would like to use an existing `.pem` file to connect via ssh to a remote system using `Windows Terminal`. Initially, the access rights for the file weren't correct and therefore it was rejected by ssh ([as documented](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)).

When I try to configure the access rights using `chmod`, I don't get an error message but I also don't get what I want (read access just for the user):

```
tim@unit:/mnt/c/Users/tim/OneDrive/Keys$ chmod -v 0400 InitialKeyPair.pem

mode of 'InitialKeyPair.pem' changed from 0555 (r-xr-xr-x) to 0400 (r--------)

tim@unit:/mnt/c/Users/tim/OneDrive/Keys$ ls -l InitialKeyPair.pem

-r-xr-xr-x 1 tim tim 1704 Feb 24 12:24 InitialKeyPair.pem
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Chmod/Chown WSL Improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/chmod-chown-wsl-improvements/)

Comment: You are on the NTFS filesystem, not in the "Linux Filesystem". Copy the file to your linux home directory and try it out there.

Comment: Thank you for your comments that pointed me in the right direction. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?